# Identifying, grouping unique entries in data frame (R)

Tags: r, dataframe, duplicates

I have a dataframe with two columns. One is an ID column (string), the second consists of strings several hundred characters long (DNA sequences). I want to identify the unique DNA sequences and group the unique groups together.

Using:

```
data$duplicates<-duplicated(data$seq, fromLast = TRUE)
```

I have successfully identified whether a specific row is a duplicate or not. This is not sufficient - I want to know whether I have 2, 3, etc. duplicates, and to which ID's do they correspond to (it is important that the ID always stays with its corresponding sequence).

Maybe something like:

> for data$duplicates = TRUE... "add number in data$grouping
>   corresponding to the set of duplicates."

I don't know how to write the code for the last part.
I appreciate any and all help, thank you.

Edit: As an example:

```
df <- data.frame(ID = c("seq1","seq2","seq3","seq4","seq5"),seq= c("AAGTCA",AGTCA","AGCCTCA","AGTCA","AGTCAGG"))
```

I would like the output to be a new column (e.g.: df$grouping) where a numeric value is given to each unique group, so in this case:

```
("1","2","3","2","4")
```

Comment: Please, could you make your example reproducible ? Just use `dput(data)`

Comment: Maybe try `rle(sort(data$duplicates))`?

Comment: @BrianDavis, unfortunately your suggestion only gives me a list of the amount of duplicated values. My output is:

Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:2] 73 32
  values : logi [1:2] FALSE TRUE

I want to see how many groups of duplicates I have. Within the 32 TRUE values there are a certain amount of groups of duplicates, and I want to know which ID's correspond to each group.

Thank you for your suggestion though.

Comment: The example clarifies your intent. I would accept Gregor's answer below. `df$grouping <- as.numeric(factor(df$seq))`

Answer (score 1):

> I would like the output to be a new column (e.g.: df$grouping) where a numeric value is given to each unique group, so in this case:

Since `df$seq` is already a factor, we can just use the level number. This is given when a factor is coerced to an integer.

```
df$grouping = as.integer(df$seq)
df
#     ID     seq grouping
# 1 seq1  AAGTCA        1
# 2 seq2   AGTCA        3
# 3 seq3 AGCCTCA        2
# 4 seq4   AGTCA        3
# 5 seq5 AGTCAGG        4
```

If, in your real data, the `seq` column is not of class `factor`, you can still use `df$grouping = as.integer(factor(df$seq))`.  By default the order of the groups will be alphabetical---you can modify this by giving the `levels` argument to `factor` in the order you want. For example, `df$grouping = as.integer(factor(df$seq, levels = unique(df$seq)))` will put the levels (and thus the grouping integers) in the order in which they first occur.

If you want to see the number of rows in each group, use `table`, e.g.

```
table(df$seq)
#  AAGTCA AGCCTCA   AGTCA AGTCAGG 
#       1       1       2       1 

table(df$grouping)
# 1 2 3 4 
# 1 1 2 1 

sort(table(df$seq), decreasing = T)
#   AGTCA  AAGTCA AGCCTCA AGTCAGG 
#       2       1       1       1
```